# using styleframe, extract the excel style from a template and apply to new excel output from dataframe

Tags: python, styleframe

I have a excel template file with styled header.  I would like to extract the style and apply it to a new excel file for a new dataframe.  The new dataframe has to have same columns as those of the template excel?.

Comment: Not the same columns name-wise, but the same number of columns.